# Watir script timeout problems with Firefox browser

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to Watir and I have this weird situation with AJAX based webapp. Application might render a notification window over the page. This notification is a JS based modal window. If I click or mouse-over the notification it vanishes.. So somewhere in my script I have:

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
...
notf = notification
notf.click if notf
```

and the method to get notification is this:

```
def notification
  if browser.div(:class => "popupContent").present?
    Notification.new(browser.div(:class => "popupContent"))
  end
end
```

Script is running fine with IE and Chrome but with Firefox I get after 60sec 'Timeout:Error' for the if statement.. When I changed code this way:

```
def notification
  begin
    browser.div(:class => "popupContent").wait_until_present(1)
    Notification.new(browser.div(:class => "popupContent"))
  rescue Exception 
    puts "timeout..."
  end
end
```

Chrome and IE work fine are working fine - just adding up 1 sec delay in case notification is not present.. But Firefox is still having 60sec timeouts in case notification is not present?!? What am I doing wrong - do I need to set/check some Firefox settings?
I have this configuration:
- Win7 OS with Firefox 17.0.1
- Ruby 1.9.3p125
- watir-webdriver (0.6.1)
- selenium-webdriver (2.26.0)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you try upgrading to the latest version of selenium-webdriver (2.27.2)? I had some problems with Firefox 17, that were resolved by the latest selenium-webdriver version.

Comment: Thanks Justin - that was it! You can also post this hint as an answer to my question and I will accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the solution is to upgrade to the latest version of selenium-webdriver (2.27.2).